# Duplicate data when generated new code / primary key, while all users are inserting the data at the same time

Tags: vb.net

I have a database that is hosted in webhosting. It can be accessed by many client users on the site.

How to prevent duplicate data especially when we generate new code [ primary key ] while all clients are inserting at the same time.

Comment: That's why it is best not to manually generate PK Ids - let the database do it.

Comment: how to prevent if we must generate PK Ids manually ?

Comment: You can avoid the 'Select MAX(id)' race condition by using a separate table with one row for each table for which you need to generate a PK. Then pull and increment this value in one atomic operation. I've seen this technique referred to as a 'Fount table' (from drinking fountain), but I don't think it's a particularly common term. Using an identity column, assuming your db supports it, is almost always the best / simplest choice, however, as Plutonix says. The Fount table comes into its own when you need, for some reason, to know what the id is going to be, before actually writing the data.

Comment: how about we use the trasaction isolation like READ COMMITED or SERIALIZE while we doing the SELECT MAX ? can it be like that ?